# RedirectToAction not redirecting to specified view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, redirecttoaction

Hi I am submitting the form once user click on login and redirecting to `LoginAction` Method.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoginAction","Login",FormMethod.Post))
{
Razor login UI..
}
```

In loginActin method i am redirecting to another view i.e
  `return RedirectToAction(ActionName);`

I have another action with `ActionName` in the above statement.
After redirecting control not passing to `ActionName`.

Comment: are you getting any error ,did you try set debug point and is it hittable ?

Comment: debug point is not hitting , and the URL not showing the controller and action its showing only localhost:Port

Comment: when url show localhost that means it is redirecting to default controller which is define in routeconfig.cs file , and if debug point not hitting check if assemblies are being loaded

Comment: Please include your `LoginAction` and `ActionName` code from the controller.